# VideoView set to initial position when putting the application in background

Tags: android

I have a VideoView in my application. The problem is that everytime when I put the application in background and I return to it, the VideoView's position is set to zero. What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods of your activity.

In `onSaveInstanceState` store the current position of the player in the Bundle.

In `onRestoreInstanceState` get the last known position of the player and set the player to that position.

Comment: The onRestoreInstanceState method is not being called. I tried using the onPause/onResume methods, but I don't have a Bundle object to use.

Comment: In onPause/onResume you could just save the current position in a variable as your application shouldn't be destroyed.

Comment: I tried using the SharedPreferences class. And it works to save the state, but another strange thing happens: even if I call the videoView.start() method, the video doesn't start until I touch the video view.